# How to limit logging per component?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, serilog

In my .NET Core app, I define a logger factory with Serilog and then pass it to various components in the system.

When I set my logging level to Debug, some components (Memcached client, for instance) completely and utterly overwhelm the logs due to how much they log.

Is there a way to specify that I want Debug for all, except certain ones?  I see that there is an `Override` entry, but I am not clear as to how to specify a specific component.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the overrides are per namespace, so you'd use something like `"Override": { "Company.Product.Feature.Or.Whatever": "Debug" }`